# zsh is showing user@ip instead of user@hostname

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have zsh installed in my MacBook Pro running Big Sur, and recently I found that it is showing user@ip instead of user@hostname, as shown below. How can I get the hostname back?

[image]

But another PC of mine running Linux is showing the right format, which I want.

I've checked agnoster.zsh-theme, and they are the same on both computers.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PS1` ?

Comment: I got %{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt) with ```echo $PS1```

Comment: That theme is using the standard `%m` prompt substitution, so the issue is probably not related to oh-my-zsh. You can confirm this with `echo ${(%):-%m}` - if that returns the ip address, it isn't omz doing this. Try the `hostname` and `scutil --get HostName` commands to see the settings on your system.  There's a bit more about hostname configuration here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/274760 .

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. I typed **echo $HOSTNAME**. It would return empty meaning hostname wasn't set. This is how you set the host name **scutil --set HostName**. Just type the name you want.